# Find and Select cells with specific text in one workbook and copy to another workbook gives Runtime Error 91

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I use the "Find" option in VBA to search cells (in workbook wbMain) containing a certain text, after which I copy the value in the next column (via the Offset function) and paste it in the second workbook (wbMainClean). I do this for every row in workbook wbMain (inner loop J).

After finishing I move to the next searchvalue (srcVal) in the outer loop. All of this goes as planned until I get Runtime Error 91 (Object variable not set) because the find function for rs1 can't find the srcVal. I thought I covered this with the if statement (If Not r1 Is Nothing Then), but apparently not. Can somebody tell me how I should correct this?
Furthermore, is my code optimized (in terms of variable declarations and not using select etc.)? I need this code to eventually run over a huge dataset, so any increase in efficiency/speed is welcome.

```
Sub AdjustMasterFile()
    
    Dim wbMain      As Workbook
    Dim wbMainClean As Workbook
    Dim wsMain      As Worksheet
    Dim wsMainClean As Worksheet
    Dim r1          As Range
    Dim r2          As Range
    Dim LR          As Long
    Dim LC          As Long
    Dim srcVal      As String
    Dim FindRange   As Range
    
    'Identify workbooks
    Set wbMainClean = Workbooks("MainImportFileVBA_Cleaned Output.xlsm")
    Set wbMain = Workbooks("MainImportFileVBA.xlsm")
    
    Set wsMainClean = wbMainClean.Sheets("Tabelle1")
    Set wsMain = wbMain.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    LR = wbMain.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LC = wbMainClean.Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    Start = Timer
    
    For i = 1 To LC
        
        srcVal = wbMainClean.Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(1, i)
        
        For j = 2 To LR
            
            Set FindRange = wsMain.Rows(i)
            
            wsMain.Activate
            
            'Find value that we are looking for in Main. Issues with making range() dynamic
            Set r1 = wsMain.Range("A" & j & ":" & "BRA" & j).Find(What:=srcVal, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart).Offset(0, 1)
            
            If Not r1 Is Nothing Then
                wsMainClean.Activate
                Set r2 = wsMainClean.Cells(j, i)
                r1.Copy r2
            End If
            
        Next j
        
    Next i
    
    Finish = Timer
    TotalTime = Finish - Start
    
    MsgBox "Totale tijd Is " & TotalTime & " seconden!"
    
End Sub
```

I used the

```
If Not r1 Is Nothing Then
```

Statement, that should cover any rows that don't have the srcVal value.

Perhaps I can try the Do statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't tag on `.Offset(0, 1)` to the `Find()` without risking a run-time error, since if the find fails there will be no range to offset from (hence "Object variable not set").

You need to move the `Offset` into the code under `If Not r1 Is Nothing Then` ie.

```
Set r1 = wsMain.Range("A" & j & ":" & "BRA" & j).Find( _
            What:=srcVal, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
            
If Not r1 Is Nothing Then
    wsMainClean.Activate
    Set r2 = wsMainClean.Cells(j, i)
    r1.Offset(0, 1).Copy r2
End If
```

If you need to increase performance, `Match` is much faster than `Find`

```
Dim m As Variant
'...
'...
m = Application.Match("*" & srcVal & "*", _
                      wsMain.Range("A" & j & ":" & "BRA" & j), 0)
            
If Not IsError(m) Then 'm would be an error value if there was no match
     wsMain.Cells(j, m+1).copy wsMainClean.Cells(j, i)                
End If
```

Comment: Thank you, this solutions solves the Error problem indeed. However do you have any suggestion to make the code run faster (besides Application.ScreenUpdating = False).

Comment: You don't need `wsMain.Activate` or `wsMainClean.Activate`